Reading and downloading email attachments using win32com with one or more mail boxes
How can I add another mailbox to the below code?
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
target_account_name = "abc@abc.com.aa"
for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName) #outlook account
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox folder
messages = inbox.Items 
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
email_subject = 'Base2'#outputDir = 'Z:\CLCM'
outputDir = 'N:\M_folder'
try:
    for message in list(messages):
        if email_subject in message.subject:
            try:
                s = message.sender
                for attachment in message.Attachments:
                    attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir, attachment.FileName))
                    print(f"attachment {attachment.FileName} from {s} saved")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error when processing emails messages:" + str(e))

New to python!
I want to know how I can add another mailbox to the above code. It always selects the first account. How can I modify this to get all the accounts we have and then select the second?

Instead of using
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox folder

use
inbox = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox folder

complete code:
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
target_account_name = "abc@abc.com.aa"
outputDir = 'N:\\M_folder'
email_subject = 'Base2'
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)  # Display the account name
    try:
        inbox = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # Inbox folder for each account
        messages = inbox.Items
        for message in list(messages):
            if email_subject in message.subject:
                try:
                    sender = message.sender
                    for attachment in message.Attachments:
                        attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir, attachment.FileName))
                        print(f"Attachment {attachment.FileName} from {sender} saved")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error when processing email messages:" + str(e))


Hello! Thanks but it still use the primary mailbox not the secondary. I want to get the secondary or checking both mailboxes.

Your code retrieving the inbox folder is not inside the for loop. See the updated code above.

Still the same, not too sure what I am missing. Below is the log
%runfile C:/untitled2.py --wdir
kevin.s.p****@***.com
I ran below code to identify the accounts, it always pick the Kevin.s.p email only
`import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folders = outlook.Folders
for i, folder in enumerate(folders):
print(i, folder.Name)`
%runfile C:/untitled3.py --wdir
0 Online Archive - kevin.s.p****@.com
1 EBIZ
2 kevin.s.p****@***.com

Did you offset your code appropriately? Hard to tell from the text in a comment.
